# Symfony - load custom global functions

Tags: php, function, symfony, load, global

I have a file with some functions (polyfills for some extensions) without namespace that should be loaded and accessible globally.

Question is where to put this file (now it in "/src/AppBundle" dir) and how to load it in Symfony? Maybe some best practice or something.

File exmaple:

```
<?php

// functions.php

define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value');

function doSomething()
{
}
```

Updated: also some functions should be loaded (in a separated file) only in "dev" environment. Maybe add "include_once" in app_dev.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put it in `/src` folder, maybe `/src/functions.php` - you can decide according to your preferences.
To load it, you can change your `composer.json` and add `files` to your `autoload` configuration, then run `composer update`.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["src/functions.php"]
}
```

So that `functions.php` is required to every request.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest a solution for case where this functions required only for "dev" environment? Put "include_once" in "web/app_dev.php" or some more "intelligent" solution?

Comment: I think that require it in `web/app_dev.php` is good enough - `require(__DIR__.'/../src/yourfile.php');` - you can also include it in your [`app/AppKernel.php`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/AppKernel.php#L21), but it's just a preference

Comment: @alex, if you want a reusable solution, you can also create a bundle to enable only on `dev` env, and include your files in your `Bundle` class, example: `class MyBundle extends Bundle { public function boot() { // include here } }`

Comment: bundle is a good solution, but i need a **global** functions without namespace, not a "local" class methods.

Comment: you just include in the `YourBundle::boot()` your function in the global space, they don't gain the namespace where the file is included.

Comment: public function boot() { require_once __DIR__ . '/functions.php'; } - no luck with this, functions isnt accessible.

Comment: No errors in "MyBundle" - functions load just fine, but accessible only in boot() method right after "require_once" statement. But if i call a function in my "AppBundle/Controller/IndexController.php" the error is "function not found".

Comment: The bundle are [booted](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/Kernel.php#L121) at the very beginner, so I'd think that maybe when you call the function `IndexController`, the bundle is not called/enable. Can I see your AppKernel.php and "MyBundle" files? Also, are you using `app.php` or `app_dev.php`?

Comment: Nope, the bundle loads before controller called. In AppKernel bundle also added at the list of the loaded bundles. I dont use app.php or app_dev.php, only MyBundle. Functions located in a separate file, placed in this bundle, in global namespace. If file included inside Bundle\Extension method (load(), boot(), etc) - functions accessible only in this methods.

Comment: Fixed this issue. Can you suggest, how to get Bundle configuration in boot() method?

Comment: When you tak about "configuration", what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: I have "MyBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php" file, whre defined bundle configuration. This configuration load in "MyBundle/DependencyInjection/MyExtension::load()". I need this config in boot() method of MyBundle class.

Comment: you can access to the container from `$this->container`. If you need to do some changes to the container when it's create, you can do that with the method `build(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder $container)` to your `MyBundle` class

Comment: with $this->container->getParameter('bundle_name.enabled') i got error "The parameter "bundle_name.param" must be defined.". The config looks like this: "bundle_name: param: 1"

Comment: that isn't a parameter. put it under `parameters:` instead of `bundle_name:`

Comment: This issue is also fixed. Thanks for help!

Comment: if you need to read the bundle configuration, use the `build(ContainerBuilder $container)` method. But you need to do so only when you need to build the container (just one time): that's what the bundle configuration is for - what's that you want to do?

Comment: In config i put some flag like "load custom functions: true\false". And check this flag in boot() every time, if its true - execute "require_once" statement, if false - do nothing.

Comment: you can have a `parameters.yml` in the Bundle directory, then in your Bundle Extension (inside the `load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)` method) you can import it (like `$loader->load('parameters.yml');`) and change its value upon the configuration value (`$configs`). Then you can call it with `getParameter` in your `boot()`